# Pauli Spin Operator General Rotation

Tags: group-theory, rotations, quantum-mechanics, quantum-groups, quantum-computation

I would like to calculate the Pauli spin operator rotation
$$ U^{\dagger } \overset{\rightharpoonup }{\sigma } U$$

where 
$$\overset{\rightharpoonup }{\sigma }=\sigma _x \overset{\rightharpoonup }{x}+\overset{\rightharpoonup }{y} \sigma _z+\sigma _z \overset{\rightharpoonup }{z}$$

and

$$U = e^{i t \omega  \sigma _z}$$

I know that this operation can be considered a rotation of the eigenvalues of the operators:

$$ U^{\dagger } \sigma _x U  =   \underset{n}{\Sigma } e_n U^{\dagger } |n'\rangle \langle n'| U=\underset{n}{\Sigma } e_n   |n'\rangle \langle n'|$$

and these eigenvalues represent the rotation axis of the overall matrix $U^{\dagger } \overset{\rightharpoonup }{\sigma } U$ (or Hamiltonian in my case of interest).

In other words, this should be really straightforward to compute without need a lot of algebra or Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formulas.  However I don't quite see how to do it most straightforwardly; any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

$
{\rm U}\left(t\right)
\equiv
\exp\left({\rm i}\,\omega t\,\sigma_{z}\right)
$
satisfies $\ddot{\rm U}\left(t\right) + \omega^{2}{\rm U}\left(t\right) = 0$
with
${\rm U}\left(0\right) = 1$ and
$\dot{{\rm U}}\left(0\right) = {\rm i}\omega\sigma_{z}$. Then

\begin{align}
{\rm U}\left(t\right)
&=
\exp\left({\rm i}\,\omega t\,\sigma_{z}\right)
=
\cos\left(\omega t\right) - {\rm i}\sin\left(\omega t\right)\,\sigma_{z}
\\[3mm]
{\rm U}^{\dagger}\left(t\right)
&=
\exp\left(-{\rm i}\,\omega t\,\sigma_{z}\right)
=
\cos\left(\omega t\right) + {\rm i}\sin\left(\omega t\right)\,\sigma_{z}
\end{align}

Define
$A\left(t\right) \equiv {\rm U}^{\dagger}\left(t\right)A{\rm U}\left(t\right)$
such that ${\rm i}\dot{A} = \omega\left[\sigma_{z},A\left(t\right)\right]$.

$$
{\rm i}\dot{\sigma}_{x}\left(t\right)
=
\omega\left[{\rm i}\sigma_{y}\left(t\right)\right]\,,
\qquad
{\rm i}\dot{\sigma}_{y}\left(t\right)
=
\omega\left[-{\rm i}\sigma_{x}\left(t\right)\right]\,;
\qquad
{{\rm d}\left[\sigma_{x}\left(t\right) + {\rm i}\sigma_{y}\left(t\right)\right]
 \over
 {\rm d}t}
=
-{\rm i}\omega
\left[\sigma_{x}\left(t\right) + {\rm i}\sigma_{y}\left(t\right)\right]
$$

\begin{align}
\sigma_{x}\left(t\right) + {\rm i}\sigma_{y}\left(t\right)
&=
\left(\sigma_{x} + {\rm i}\sigma_{y}\right)\exp\left(-{\rm i}\omega t\right)
\\[3mm]
\sigma_{x}\left(t\right) - {\rm i}\sigma_{y}\left(t\right)
&=
\left(\sigma_{x} - {\rm i}\sigma_{y}\right)\exp\left({\rm i}\omega t\right)
\end{align}
Then
$$
\sigma_{x}\left(t\right)
=
\sigma_{x}\cos\left(\omega t\right)
+
\sigma_{y}\sin\left(\omega t\right)\,,
\qquad
\sigma_{y}\left(t\right)
=
-\sigma_{x}\sin\left(\omega t\right)
+
\sigma_{y}\cos\left(\omega t\right)
$$

Comment: I'm familiar with the Euler expansion for the exponentiated pauli operator, but I dont immediately see how it follows from the differential equation statement?  Or is it not a constructive derivation, in other words, are you just saying that both, exponentials and sin/cos will satisfy the 2nd Order ODE. And then you match boundary conditions for the two ways of expressing the particular solution?

Comment: @AimForClarity That works since $\sigma_{i}^{2} = 1\,, i = x, y, z$.

Comment: oh ok so you're Taylor expanding the exponential?